# here-maps C# .NET Windows Forms simple example

Tags: here-api

I am looking for the simplest possible sample that uses .NET c# windows forms to display a here map. A WPF sample would also be ok.

I have searched my fingers off - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a form in your project and add a `WebBrowser` control to the form set to the desired URL. This is essentially using IE to display the site in the application.